# How to convert numbers and letters a string in a list into integers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert this list

```
a = ['45 inches', '45 inches', '44 inches', '42 inches', '41 inches', '41 inches']
```

into

```
a = ['45', '45', '44', '42', '41', '41']
```

Could someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would be helpful to know what you've already tried and why it didn't work

Comment: Logically, how would you isolate the number if it was on paper and not in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your condition of convertion. If you want to get only the item after by splitting, try :

```
a1 = [k.split()[0] for k in a]
```

If you want to find all numeric charcaters, try :

```
a2 = [''.join([m for m in k if m.isnumeric()]) for k in a]
```

Comment: Thank you!. That's what I was looking for :) Much appreciated for help.

Answer (score 1):

using Regex:

```
import re
a = ['45 inches','45 inches','44 inches','42inches','41inches','41inches']
res = []
for i in a:
    m = re.search(r"\b(\d{2})\b", i)
    if m:
        res.append(m.group())
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use regular expressions to search for groups of digits within the strings.

```
import re
a = ['45 inches', '45 inches', '44 inches', '42 inches', '41 inches', '41 inches']

out = []
for string in a: 
    nums = re.search(r"(\d+)", string)
    if nums: 
        out.append(nums.group(1))

print(out)
# ['45', '45', '44', '42', '41', '41']
```